# exception while logging using fluentd logger with Google Stackdriver

Tags: amazon-ec2, stackdriver

I'm using Google stackdriver on AWS EC2. Followed all the Steps as available for installing stackdriver on EC2.

Verified following

**A) fluentd & collectd status**

ps ax | grep fluentd
11429 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto fluentd

ps ax | grep collectd
 1341 ?        Ssl    0:02 /opt/stackdriver/collectd/sbin/stackdriver-collectd -C /opt/stackdriver/collectd/etc/collectd.conf -P /var/run/stackdriver-agent.pid
11431 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto collectd

**B) Current credentials availability**

sudo cat /etc/google/auth/application_default_credentials.json

However still getting stackoverflow error as I log any error in the system

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:153)
    java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:193)
    java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:426)
    java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:491)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.connect(RawSocketSender.java:83)
    org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.reconnect(RawSocketSender.java:95)
    org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.flush(RawSocketSender.java:186)
    org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.flushBuffer(RawSocketSender.java:152)
    org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.send(RawSocketSender.java:164)
    org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.emit(RawSocketSender.java:147)
    org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.emit(RawSocketSender.java:129)
    org.fluentd.logger.sender.RawSocketSender.emit(RawSocketSender.java:124)
    org.fluentd.logger.FluentLogger.log(FluentLogger.java:101)
    org.fluentd.logger.FluentLogger.log(FluentLogger.java:86)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your item **A** does not show any trace of the `google-fluentd` service. The best way to find out the status of the Stackdriver logging agent is by running `sudo service google-fluentd status`. The same goes for the Stackdriver monitoring agent (`sudo service stackdriver-agent status`).

If your logging agent is indeed not running, that would explain the failure of the Java logging library to connect to it. The `StackOverflow` exception is probably due to some configuration that causes Java to log all errors, including errors resulting from logging, resulting in infinite recursion.

To be able to answer this fully, we'd need to see the status of the logging service (as described above) and the configuration of your Java logger.